# HTTPClient 4.x Connection reuse not happening

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I tried the following example of Apache http client:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java

I set the max pool size as 5 and run ten threads. After running this code, when I check netstat , I see 10 TCP connections being open. I was expecting the connections to be reused. Why is this ? Am I missing something ?

Code snippet is as below:

```
public class ClientMultiThreadedExecution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(
    new Scheme("http", 18080, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

    ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5);
    cm.setMaxTotal(5);


    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
    try {
        // create an array of URIs to perform GETs on
        String uri = "http://test.webservice.com:18080/TestServlet";
        String data = "This is a test message";

        System.out.println("Started at: " + new Date());
        // creating 10 threads
        PostThread[] threads = new PostThread[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        threads[i] = new PostThread(httpclient, httpPost, data, i + 1);
            threads[i].start();
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

       // join the threads
        for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
            threads[j].join();
        }

    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        System.out.println("Ended at: " + new Date());
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}

/**
 * A thread that performs a POST.
 */
static class PostThread extends Thread {

    private final HttpClient httpClient;
    private final HttpContext context;
    private final HttpPost httpPost;
    private final int id;
    private final String data;

    public PostThread(HttpClient httpClient, HttpPost httpPost, String data, int id) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        this.context = new BasicHttpContext();
        this.httpPost = httpPost;
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * Executes the PostMethod and prints some status information.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //System.out.println(id + " - about to get something from " + httpPost.getURI());

        try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("XML",data));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));

            // execute the method
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, context);

            //System.out.println(id + " - get executed");
            // get the response body as an array of bytes
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                System.out.println("Success");

            //Is this step necessary ?? Need to check as only status code is required
            //httpPost.abort();
            //HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            //And this ?
            //EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            httpPost.abort();
            System.out.println(id + " - error: " + e);
        }
    }

}}
```

Comment: The solution was to specifically mention the protocol version as HTTP_1_1: `HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);`. The pooling then worked.

Comment: What do we need to keep in place of params  means what value and where do we need to place this statement in the code

Answer (score 12):

---

```
        //Is this step necessary ?? Need to check as only status code is required
        //httpPost.abort();
        //HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        //And this ?
        //EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```

---

Guess what? It is.

One **MUST** ensure response content gets consumed in order to have the underlying connection released back to the connection manager. Invocation of either `EntityUtils#consume` or `httpUriRequest#abort` triggers release of connection back to the pool. The difference is that the former attempts to keep the connection alive while the latter does not.

Comment: How about this code block ? `catch (Exception e) {
            httpPost.abort();
            System.out.println(id + " - error: " + e);
        }` Whenever an exception occurs, httpPost.abort() is called. However, what I observe is that, the same aborted connection is still being handed out to other threads and all of them error out with the message 'java.io.IOException: Request already aborted' . Why does this happen ?

Comment: @Dunxton Aborted connections get discarded and evicted from the pool immediately. You are trying to re-use an aborted request. Do not do that. Request objects are cheap.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct one... still valid, even 9 year after.

Answer (score 0):

in this codes explain how to Reuse Of Aborted Connections:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/test/java/org/apache/http/conn/TestConnectionReuse.java